# Why does Directory work with RewriteRule, but DirectoryMatch fail?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.4

The `DirectoryMatch` directive generally works fine for me.

However, when combined with `RewriteRule`, it can fail. And I don't understand why.

Now, I'm not asking for a workaround which would avoid the `DirectoryMatch` directive entirely, such as by combining the `Directory` and `Import` directives.

My question is specifically about the `DirectoryMatch` directive. To make it work, what am I missing? What am I not understanding about it? About the rewrite module? Or something else?

By the way, please note that chaining the `RewriteRule`s doesn't enable the `DirectoryMatch` directive to succeed with this.

No `.htaccess` files are allowed. (`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` contains the `AllowOverride None` directive.)

I have uploaded the following files. They are already gzipped:

```bash
$ ls -dlU `find test-{d,m}*`
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  9 06:07 test-directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  439 Feb  8 14:17 test-directory/test.html.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  9 06:06 test-match
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  439 Feb  8 14:18 test-match/test.html.gz
```

and I have these settings in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/local-settings.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine On
<Directory /var/www/html>
   Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/test-directory>
   LogLevel debug
   Header set Cache-Control no-store
   RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz" -s
   RewriteRule ^test\.html$ $0.gz
   RewriteRule ^test\.html\.gz$ - [T=text/html,E=no-gzip:1]
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/test-match">
   LogLevel debug
   Header set Cache-Control no-store
   RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz" -s
   RewriteRule ^test\.html$ $0.gz
   RewriteRule ^test\.html\.gz$ - [T=text/html,E=no-gzip:1]
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Basically, if the implicit `.gz` extension when appended to the requested filename exists as a file, then:

```
Append `.gz`;

Serve the correct media type; and

Prevent mod_deflate from double-gzipping.
```

Navigating to `test.html` under `Directory` works. But under `DirectoryMatch` it produces "404 Not Found". The error log shows:

```bash
$ sudo tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/error.log
[{...}:07:45.669167 2024] [core:info] [pid 919696:tid 281473097625984] {...} AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/test-match/test.html
```

So why doesn't the version with `DirectoryMatch` find the file?

Now in another set of test directories, I have uploaded the following files. They are not gzipped:

```bash
$ ls -dlU `find test-simple*`
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:51 test-simple-dir
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  778 Feb  8 14:17 test-simple-dir/test.html.new
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 12 13:51 test-simple-match
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  778 Feb  8 14:17 test-simple-match/test.html.new
```

and I have these additional, simpler settings in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/local-settings.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/test-simple-dir>
   LogLevel debug
   Header set Cache-Control no-store
   RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.new" -s
   RewriteRule ^test\.html$ test.html.new [END]
</Directory>

<DirectoryMatch "^/var/www/html/test-simple-match">
   LogLevel debug
   Header set Cache-Control no-store
   RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.new" -s
   RewriteRule ^test\.html$ test.html.new [END]
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Basically, if the `.new` extension when appended to the requested filename exists as a file, then:

```
Append `.new`.
```

Again, navigating to `test.html` under `Directory` works. But under `DirectoryMatch` it produces "404 Not Found". The error log shows:

```bash
[{...}:29:30.136369 2024] [deflate:debug] [pid 919696:tid 281473122804096] mod_deflate.c(869): {...} AH01384: Zlib: Compressed 778 to 404 : URL /test-simple-dir/test.html.new
[{...}:29:47.041233 2024] [core:info] [pid 919696:tid 281473262170496] {...} AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html
```

Again, why doesn't the version with `DirectoryMatch` find the file?

Increasing to `LogLevel trace6` produced, in the error log:

```bash
$ sudo tail  /var/log/apache2/error.log
[{...}:03:10.217345 2024] [core:trace3] [pid 938032:tid 281473262170496] request.c(360): [client {...}:27372] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /test-simple-match/test.html
[{...}:03:10.217356 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 938032:tid 281473262170496] mod_rewrite.c(487): [client {...}:27372] {...} - - [{...}/sid#ffff9b6c4208][rid#ffff984370a0/initial] [perdir ^/var/www/html/test-simple-match/] applying pattern '^test\\.html$' to uri '/var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html'
[{...}:03:10.217362 2024] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 938032:tid 281473262170496] mod_rewrite.c(487): [client {...}:27372] {...} - - [{...}/sid#ffff9b6c4208][rid#ffff984370a0/initial] [perdir ^/var/www/html/test-simple-match/] pass through /var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html
[{...}:03:10.217376 2024] [core:info] [pid 938032:tid 281473262170496] [client {...}:27372] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html
```

For diagnostic purposes, in both the simple `Directory` and `DirectoryMatch` sections, I temporarily added, immediately after `RewriteCond`, this `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/?path=$1 [R,L]
```

Under `Directory`, the result was a redirect to `https://example.com/?path=test.html` as desired.

But under `DirectoryMatch`, it was to `https://example.com/?path=/var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html`. In other words, to the absolute file path.

So, under `DirectoryMatch`, how can I access the relative file path when using the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives?

Apache version:

```bash
$ /usr/sbin/apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.56 (Debian)
Server built:   2023-04-02T03:06:01
```

Debian version:

```bash
$ cat /etc/debian_version
11.9
```

Comment: Presumably there are no other `<Directory(Match)>` containers or stray `.htaccess` files along the directory tree that might be overriding this? I would certainly test this without the preceding condition in case the `REQUEST_FILENAME` is not as expected. Or maybe the directory-prefix is not as expected. Try removing the `^` prefix from the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. Did either of these trigger a rewrite? (Change to a temp redirect to make it easier to test.) Also try rewriting to an absolute filesystem path (or root-relative URL-path if testing a redirect).

Comment: ... although "redirecting" to a _relative_ substitution string will expose the directory-prefix (absolute filesystem path) - so it would be good to at least test that.

Comment: @MrWhite When I removed the `^` prefix from the `RewriteRule` pattern, navigating to `/test-simple-match/test.html` produced "404 Bad Request".

Comment: Yes, the "condition" is the `RewriteCond` (Rewrite Condition) directive that precedes the `RewriteRule`. If removing `^`  gets a "result" then there must be something before `test.html` in the path that is matched. I'm guessing this is the absolute file-path (so, `/var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html` in your 2nd example) - which is what happens when mod_rewrite is used inside `<Files>`, `<Location>` and `<If>` containers - which are also _merged_ late (after the request has been mapped back to the filesystem).

Comment: cont... I wasn't aware that this would also happen to `<DirectoryMatch>` which is also processed later (after all other `<Directory>` containers and `.htaccess` files), but before the other containers mentioned. (Unfortunately I don't have a server to hand I can quickly test.) I assume you mean "400 Bad Request" (not "404")? The issue here would likely be the relative _substitution_ string - what does it think it is relative to? As mentioned, change this to an external redirect to expose this file-path. (And/Or examine the error log.)

Comment: "I'm guessing this is the absolute file-path (so, `/var/www/html/test-simple-match/test.html`" - You could test this by capturing the path and including this in an external redirect. eg. `RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/?path=$1 [R,L]` (where `example.com` would literally be `example.com`, or some other benign domain, not the domain in question).

Comment: @MrWhite I added diagnostic info.